# How to increase SWRevealViewController sidebar Width?

Tags: objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I used my project third party application `SWReavelViewController`. But i can adjust my Side bar width. Is this any possible to adjust the width.

Comment: See my answer, you can customize it according to your requirement withour code

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is:

**1.** Open the `SWRevealViewController.m` file and then you get the `_initDefaultProperties` Method.

**2.** In this `_initDefaultProperties` method looks like following:

```
- (void)_initDefaultProperties
{
    _frontViewPosition = FrontViewPositionLeft;
    _rearViewPosition = FrontViewPositionLeft;
    _rightViewPosition = FrontViewPositionLeft;
    _rearViewRevealWidth = 260.0f; //  In this method you can change the side bar width
    _rearViewRevealOverdraw = 60.0f;
    _rearViewRevealDisplacement = 40.0f;
    _rightViewRevealWidth = 260.0f;
    _rightViewRevealOverdraw = 60.0f;
    _rightViewRevealDisplacement = 40.0f;
    _bounceBackOnOverdraw = YES;
    _bounceBackOnLeftOverdraw = YES;
    _stableDragOnOverdraw = NO;
    _stableDragOnLeftOverdraw = NO;
    _presentFrontViewHierarchically = NO;
    _quickFlickVelocity = 250.0f;
    _toggleAnimationDuration = 0.3;
    _toggleAnimationType = SWRevealToggleAnimationTypeSpring;
    _springDampingRatio = 1;
    _replaceViewAnimationDuration = 0.25;
    _frontViewShadowRadius = 2.5f;
    _frontViewShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.5f);
    _frontViewShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
    _frontViewShadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    _userInteractionStore = YES;
    _animationQueue = [NSMutableArray array];
    _draggableBorderWidth = 0.0f;
    _clipsViewsToBounds = NO;
    _extendsPointInsideHit = NO;
}
```

**What you have to do-** instead of `_rearViewRevealWidth = 260.0f;` this line `_rearViewRevealWidth = Your_value.0f`, change value according to your requirement.

You can customize it according to your requirement.

Thank you :)